# Angular2 templateUrl with Jade?

Tags: javascript, express, pug, angular, mean

Is there any way to use Jade in an Angular2 templateUrl without webpack?

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
templateUrl: 'my-app.component.jade'
})
```

my-app.component.jade

```
ul
  li One
  li Two
  li Three
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, in build dev from dist serve html file in the right location what component links. In build progress use gulp-jade in simple task for example:

```
gulp.task('html:build', () =>
  gulp.src(PATH.src.jade)
    .pipe(jade())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(PATH.dest.app.component))
);
```

Check out my complexity Angular2 boilerplate project with Jade templates on GitHub --> https://github.com/NN77/ng2-complexity/blob/master/gulpfile.ts